# CentOS ELRepo Kernel installing VMware

Tags: centos, kernel, vmware

Already installed VMware Workstation 9 on my Linux CentOS 6.5 Final with  `3.10.40-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64` running kernel.
When I open VMware Workstation, it asks me to locate the Kernel Headers  3.10.40-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64.

THESE MESSAGE: I get on the internet, my kernel version is different of that message says. Outside, it is all the same.

[image: message]

I've tried to download the ELRepo Headers (lt-kernel-headers-3.10.40-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64.rpm), unzip and put in the way of VMware, however it does not recognize. Apparently I must be doing something wrong. What do I actually download, install and which path should point to the VMware Kernel C Header configuration to work?

The official page of the [ELRepo](http://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-ml), he talks to use the original Kernel conferring with `glibc`, however, already tried using the original kernel as a way to configure the VMware Kernel Headers C and does not work because the name of the kernels do not match indeed.

I wonder what it is the Kernel Header?

Comment: I think kernel-devel package will solve this issue. Just a guess, never tried out VMWare products.

Comment: Tnx for ur help. But then I just downloaded and what path I should use after unzip it?

Comment: I dont think you need to download the zip or tar file. Did you try with yum? I mean like this:  `yum install kernel-devel`

Comment: tnx beginer, ur comment helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED.

1-Downloaded the

```
kernel-lt-devel-3.10.40-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64.rpm
```

from http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/elrepo/archive/kernel/el6/x86_64/RPMS/

2-Installed  (just executing the file)

3-Pointed de VMware configuration to

```
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64/include/linux/
```

When the VMware start, another error appeared. Said that just cant load the module vmci of vmware.

4-So, compile the vmci module:

```
vmware-modconfig --console --build-mod vmci
```

5-install the module:

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-pbm vmci
```

OR

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

next, I tested:

```
modprobe vmci
```

SUCCESS

Just fine with my vmware running.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo yum install kernel-devel-3.10.40-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64
```

then run the VMware setup again

Answer (score -2):

Follow the steps below:

```
uname -a
```

then use your version number you get from `uname -a` to install the correct `kernel-devel` i.e.

```
yum install kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: this general idea was [already posted as an answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158605/117549) over 2 years ago